Graphical Interface Scaling Bug on Kubuntu 24.04
I'm currently facing an issue. I have an Asus ROG Flow X13 computer running Kubuntu 24.04, and I'm having a problem with the graphical interface scaling.
Since this computer has a 2560 x 1600 screen, the interface is very small, so I set the global scale in the display settings to 200%.
However, sometimes when I start the computer, most of the time everything is in order and properly scaled, but occasionally, the icons are no longer scaled correctly and become very small, while the rest of the interface maintains the correct scale.
To temporarily fix this problem, I have to go to the display settings, set a different global scaling percentage, apply it, and then switch back to 200% to force the computer to reset to my customized scale.
What can I do to avoid having to perform these steps every time this happens? How can I set the scale to 200% permanently so it never changes?

You are asking a video related question but have failed to include the make and model of the video card, the driver used and the kernel being used. Please edit the question and add this info.
